# Weblogic url-rewriting true only if cookies are off

Tags: java, cookies, url-rewriting, weblogic

I want to have an application deployed on a weblogic container that uses url rewriting only if cookies are disabled in the browser.

I need this because even if the browser has cookie enabled, on the first request url-rewritting is used. So the url looks something like

> `mysite.com/go;jsessionid=YZLVTW3P1fPdLFc28BxgN72zhmXNGMpkYpwnTflDGJy9Gvp7R61n!-128874051`

And I wold like it to be

> `mysite.com/go`

if cookies are enabled and append the jsessionid only if cookies are disabled.

I have now the following configuration in weblogic.xml

```
<session-descriptor>
        <debug-enabled>true</debug-enabled>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
        <url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
        <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
        <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
</session-descriptor>
```

Does any one know if it is possible to enable

```
<url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
```

only if cookies are disabled?

How would you do something like this? Java code filter?

More details: 
what I need is to have behaviour that is like this

```
<session-descriptor>        
        <url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
        <cookies-enabled>false</cookies-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
```

and

```
<session-descriptor>        
        <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
        <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
```

Or something that mimics this (even java filter would be good), url-rewriting-enabled only if cookies are disabled. As I said on the first request I do get the jsessionid even though cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say you should not turn on `url-rewriting-enabled` if you also turn on `cookie-secure`:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1071982

I found multiple other references that also mention, no, you cannot have both secure cookies and url rewriting enabled. This source goes into greater detail on the merits of each to help you make a choice:

http://j2eesecurity.blogspot.com/2007/11/cookies-vs-url-rewriting.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to have <session-descriptor>  
  <url-rewriting-enabled>true</url-rewriting-enabled>
  <cookies-enabled>false</cookies-enabled>
 </session-descriptor>                                                                and                                                                               <session-descriptor>  
  <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
  <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
 </session-descriptor>         or something that mimics this behaviour. Basically I need them both at the same time.